# Command Prompt Search Directory and Sub-Directories

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am looking to search a directory that also has sub-directories for any and all files ending in the extension `.kfm`

I have managed to pick up all the files from the current directory using `dir *.kfm` but I also need to loop through each of the results in a `for` loop so I can add additional code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Don't expect others to put more effort in your task than you yourself. First do your own research and try to code - when you get stuck present your  code here with a [mcve]. [SO] isn't a code writing service but provides tons of examples you could learn from.

Comment: @LotPings I am in no way expecting a code writing service here, alas I wouldn't have any reputation should I be so! I am here simply to extend my knowledge and dig myself out of a metaphorical hole I am currently in.

Comment: Well the research part of your own couldn't have been very intense, see [for /r](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html).

Comment: @LotPings Alas, I have come across `for /r` since posting this question. It is currently in my script but my problem now resides in checking each iteration's path for a certain folder. THIS seems to be where I should have asked my question!

Comment: This deviates to much from the current question -  so ask a new one. Hint: switch to a `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B/S "X:\path\to\start\*.kfm"^|findstr /i "foldertocheck"') Do Echo %%A` If you want to exclude folders insert `/V` following findstr.

Answer (score 0):

I know you did not ask for a PowerShell solution, but it is pretty straightforward. From your earlier comment, I added filtering out those files whose path includes `\UPT\`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\the\dir' -Recurse -File -Filter '*.kfm' |
    Where-Object { -not ( $_.FullName -like "*[/\]UPT[/\]*") }
    ForEach-Object {
        # work on the $_.FullName file here
    }
```